# disorder of eye

Tags: optometry, artificial-tear-eye-drops

my right eye no is -5.00 cyl.-1.50 sph at 170 axis and left eye no is -2.00 cyl.-9.00sph at 180 axis .what should I do to save it .as I am taking Co dorsal drops. science three years on doctors advice and doctor is satisfied with my version as my eyes are weak since my birth I want to improve and save my eye sight. Please help me

Comment: Could you edit your question to make it easier to read?